# ENOENT when trying to access network share via drive letter in Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, fs

I'm writing a NodeJS application that enumerates files in a configurable directory. I'd like for it to work with network shares that are mapped to a drive letter. I thought this would be simple:

```
require('fs').readdirSync('Y:\\')
```

But that gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'Y:\'
```

I have also tried it with forward slashes, and accessing a subdirectory instead of the drive root, but the result is the same. Accessing local drives works fine.

The network drive is definitely connected, and I can access it via `dir Y:\` in cmd.

Comment: Drive letter mappings are a per-user setting.  So if you run node with a different user account, or run it with UAC elevation, then it doesn't know what Y: means.  Always favor the UNC name.

Comment: Ah, that's the issue. I have VSCode configured to run as administrator. It doesn't work from the integrated terminal in VSCode either. UNC name works. Thanks!